# How to implement a efficient timeout in java

Tags: java, optimization, timeout, timertask

There are `n` object which perform some actions. After performing an action a timestamp will be updated. Now I want to implement a timeout-thread which verifies if a timestamp is older than for example 60 seconds.

My first solution was to do that with a thread (while-loop + sleep) which is holding a list with all objects including the last timestamp. Now I have the problem that there is a worst-case scenario where the thread needs 59 seconds plus sleep time to decide for a timeout.

I’m searching for a solution like a Timer where it is possible to update the delay time.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm finding a hard time understanding your logic. Would you please show a sample code for what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Something makes me think that you want to monitor some threads for a "work complete" event. You could use `CountDownLatch` for this purpose.

Comment: What happens when an object completes in time? And what happens when they do not? Do you allow them to continue? or do they need to stop?  There're several options. Could you add your goal to the question?  and you may get the best fit for this problem.

Comment: another clarification: When you say "There are n object which perform some actions..." I guess you mean "n threads ..." ?

Answer (score 2):

I think using a monitor object with wait/notify is reasonable (you may use Condition with await/signal if you are using JDK >= 5)

idea is simple:

Worker thread:

```
doYourActualWork();
synchronized(jobFinishedMonitor) {
    updateTimestamp();

    jobFinishedMonitor.notify();
}
```

Timeout thread:

```
synchronized(jobFinishedMonitor) {
    while(within60Second(timestamp)) {
        jobFinishedMonitor.wait(60);
    }
    if (within60Second(timestamp)) {
        timeoutHappened=true;
    }
 }
 if (timeoutHappened) {
     // do timeout handling
 }
```

Comment: Should be wait(60_000) for 60 seconds

Answer (score 1):

For the question, it's not clear what you want to do with the timeout. Here I present you two options to implement a lightweight timeout: monitored vs controlled.

**Monitored Timeout**

For a global timer, you can use the `Timer` facility from the JDK:

```
public TimeoutTask implements TimerTask {
    List<MonitorableObject>  objects;
    public TimeoutTask(List<MonitorableObject> objects) {
        // make sure you can share this collection concurrently, 
        // e.g. copyonwritearraylist
        this.objects = objects;
    }
    public void run() {
       // objects -> filter(isTimeOut(currentTime)) -> do something
    }
}

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimeoutTask(myObjectList), 0,60*1000); // repeat each 60secs
```

There's a similar construction possible using a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
// Note that I can use here TimeoutTask b/c TimerTask is a Runnable - 
// this is just for the example. You'd better implement a plain runnable.
scheduler.schedule(new TimeoutTask(myObjectList), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I prefer the `ScheduledExecutorService` above the `Timer` facility, as the `SchedulerExecutor` can hold a pool of threads. Also, the underlying threadpool can be used for other operations invoking `scheduledExecutorService.execute(...)` for immediate concurrent execution (not scheduled), making it a generic executor facility, rather than a dedicated timer function.

In both cases, you'll need to take special care to safely get the timeout value from your the objects you are monitoring. Typically, you will use a synchronized method in the object to ask for it's timeout status.

**Enforced Timeout**

The ExecutorService provides you with an API to execute a set of tasks within a given timeout. e.g.

```
List<Callable<?>> myTasks = ...;
// populate myTasks with Callable`s that wrap your intended execution

ExecutorService executorService = ... ;

List<Future<?>> results = executorService.invokeAll(myTasks, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

After this method returns, you can ask every Future whether it succeeded within the time given.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt the thread every time you update a timestamp. Then it will loop, find nothing to do, sleep, and if nothing else has happened to the timestamp, expire it. If it gets interrupted a second time, so much the better. And at all times it should never sleep for longer than 60 minus (current time minus the oldest timestamp).