# Java No Response from native method call

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to get a value from native method in my Java program. But for some reason, the native method is not responding.My program is stuck over there. So, If no response from native method for 2mins, then my java code should have the control again and proceed further.
How should I implement this? Simply I want control back from native method after some time..

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11642222/4066277

Answer (score 1):

you can start a runnable so that thread will call the native method you want , and this will be bugged for 2 mins not the main application.

```
  Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            yourObject.yourFuctionCall();
        }
    }
   new Thread(updateRunnable).start();
```

hope it helps